# Send search results to json with rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, vue.js

I am currently working on a simple search feature on a Rails app. I'm using Vue.js, so I'm feeding everything to the frontend using Rails' JSON builder. For the search I have the controller and model setup as so:

The controller:

```
def index
  if params[:search]
    @strains = Strain.search(params[:search]).order("created_at DESC")
  else
    @strains = Strain.all.order("created_at DESC")
  end
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { render :json => @strains }
  end
end
```

The model:

```
  def self.search(search)
    where('title LIKE ?', '%#{search}%')
  end
```

The view:

```
<%= form_tag(strains_path, :method => "get") do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Search Strains" %>
  <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
<% end %>
```

When I type in the search, I see it update the params in the URL, but nothing happens to the output on the page. I'm thinking it has something to do with the JSON. This is my ready function inside the Vue component.

```
ready: function() {
    var that;
    that = this;
    $.ajax({
      url: '/strains.json',
      success: function(res){
        that.strains = res;
      }
    });
  }
```

I'm watching the log and it seems like it will render the search for HTML, but not JSON.

Here is the log:

```
Started GET "/strains.json" for ::1 at 2016-05-23 21:40:32 -0400
Processing by StrainsController#index as JSON
  Strain Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "strains".* FROM "strains"  ORDER BY created_at DESC
Completed 200 OK in 2ms (Views: 1.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)


Started GET "/strains?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=Test" for ::1 at 2016-05-23 21:41:07 -0400
Processing by StrainsController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "search"=>"Test"}
  Strain Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "strains".* FROM "strains" WHERE (title LIKE '%Test%')  ORDER BY created_at DESC
  Rendered strains/index.html.erb within layouts/application (1.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 17ms (Views: 16.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)


Started GET "/strains.json" for ::1 at 2016-05-23 21:41:07 -0400
Processing by StrainsController#index as JSON
  Strain Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "strains".* FROM "strains"  ORDER BY created_at DESC
Completed 200 OK in 2ms (Views: 1.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.1ms)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it is your main issue but it looks your where clause is using single quotes, thus is not picking up that variable. You need to use double quotes if you want to use ruby string interpolation.

```
irb(main):006:0> foo = 5
=> 5
irb(main):007:0> 'this is my number #{foo}'
=> "this is my number \#{foo}"
irb(main):008:0> "this is my number #{foo}"
=> "this is my number 5"
```

So you want:

```
  def self.search(search)
    where('title LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")
  end
```

Comment: Just fixed. But I think the issue is rendering the json in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the `dataType` option to expect JSON data for the return value.  You can do it like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/strains.json',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(res){
    that.strains = res;
  }
});
```

Comment: Do I put format.json { render formats: [:json] } inside the if statement?

Comment: @Dileet I removed the `format.json` from my answer.  After reading through your question again, what you have is fine.  I believe that adding the `dataType` to the Ajax call should be enough to do the trick.

Comment: It still wont update the table with the search result. This is the url http://localhost:3000/strains?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=Test

Comment: Can you add your Rails logs to the question?  I'd like to see everything between and including the `Started` and `Completed` lines for this action.

Comment: Edited. If I remove the respond_to block and add "render :json => @strains" inside the search if block, it sends the right json. I think the issue is I need a way to push an update to the json file when there is a search param.

Comment: Ah, that's interesting.  Rails should be picking up the `format` parameter from the route.  Can you also add your route definition for `/strains` and show the `rake routes` output?  There may be something wrong in the route that's causing this.

Comment: The only line in the route file that's uncommented is 'resources :strains'